# Import internal node module in typescript breaks setTimeout API

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to import an internal node module `url` in browser environment with webpack and typescript.

As used to do, I installed `@types/node` for typescript, but it seems that some other API breaks.

For example, in node v14.8.0, when use `setTimeout`, we got a `Timeout` Object as return value. But in browsers, we actually got a number.

How can I solve this conflict? Heartfelt thanks.

Comment: Browsers implementation and node's implementation are two different things. For browser: [timeoutID is going to be returned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), for node [a Timeout instance](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args) and this is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `window` before `setTimeout`.

```js
const a: Timeout = setTimeout(() => ...);       // Node.js API
const b: number = window.setTimeout(() => ...); // browser API
```